# How can I use COUNT in the same query with ROUND() and AVG()?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a query where I need to first count the tickets sold for spectacles in a theater, then calculate the average number of tickets sold in  each theater and to be round it to two decimal place and these values must to be sort by the number of tickets sold.
In principle, I want to find the average number of tickets sold for each theater.
I tried so many different options, but I have different errors.
When I tried to run this, this error appeared :

> SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

```
SELECT
    t.id_theater
    , s.id_spectacle
    , ROUND((AVG(COUNT(tickets.id_ticket))), 2) average_tickets_theatre
FROM
    tickets tick
    , theater t
    , spectacles s
WHERE
    tick.id_spectacle = s.id_spectacle
    AND t.id_theater = s.id_theater
GROUP BY
    t.id_theater
    , s.id_spectacle
ORDER BY
    average_tickets_theatre
```

I tried to add the HAVING clause, but another error appeared:

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

I'm sure that the problem consists in the fact that I'm trying to use COUNT with ROUND() and AVG(), but I really don't know what do to at this point and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please look at your tags (below the question). Oracle or SQL Server? Why do you have the Oracle SQL Developer tag? (Most likely should be removed). Then - why a `having` clause? You didn't explain any condition about excluding any groups after aggregation. Should we just forget that comment in your question?

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag as you are clearly using Oracle

Comment: what are you truing to  do ? please explain the problem and provide sample data and desired output

Comment: taking the average of a count(*) - scalar value - makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

The average number of tickets per spectacle is going to be the total number of tickets divided by the number of spectacles.  A pretty simple way to calculate this is:

```
SELECT s.id_theater,
       COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT id_spectacle) as average_tickets_theatre
FROM tickets t JOIN
     spectacles s
     ON  t.id_spectacle = s.id_spectacle
GROUP BY t.id_theater
ORDER BY average_tickets_theatre;
```

I'll let you handle the rounding of the value.

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.